# Android AlarmManager Triggering

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an alarm which I can schedule to go off at a certain time.  The thing is, when I shedule it into the future, it works at exactly the minute I set it for.  It works as it should.  But the problem is, if I schedule it in the past, it goes off immediately.

For example, if it is now 3:30pm and I schedule it for 3:35pm, it fires at 3:35pm.  But if it is 3:30pm and I schedule it for 3:25pm, it fires immediately since it is in the past.

What I want it to do is, if it is int he past, just ignore it until the interval time passes.

Here is the code:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,     ApplicationClass.AlertNotifyID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     long milliSeconds24Hours = 86400000; //86400000 which is 24 hours in milliseconds
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  GetNotificationTime(context), milliSeconds24Hours, sender);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore it until the interval time passes." do you mean you want it to go off at that time on the next day? If so you'll have to manually check your timestamp and if it is before current time then you'll have to roll it forward by one day and then set it with the AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it to check if the scheduled time is in the past, and if so set your alarm to start the next day.